# Why doesn't this segfault

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, printf

I stumbled across something "interesting" and I cant put my finger why the behaviour isn't coherent.

Check this code.

```
char buf[100];
sprint(buf,"%s",bla);
```

Simple, right. It's easy to understand what is going on when `bla` is a `NULL` pointer.

This should always segfault right!?

In one machine the executable segfaults, on another (my development machine), it's just business as usual.

My devel PC is running `Windows7` and I'm compiling with `gcc/MingW`. The computer where this is crashing is `XP` and it does have `Visual studio 6` installed.

Why doesn't this crash on my PC?

Comment: Just to mention it: I know this is test code, but in most cases you probably should use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`.

Comment: Unless you need to test your code for compatibility with seriously wonky compilers, I'd think about replacing Visual Studio 6 with something from this century.

Comment: It is indeed undefined behavior as all answers say - but, just a thought: Are you *positive* bla is null? is it possible that it is uninitialized? That is a more common reason for difference between systems.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ISO C99: 7.19.6.3 The printf function`

*Synopsis*

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

`The printf function is equivalent to fprintf with the argument stdout interposed before the arguments to printf.`

`7.19.6.1   The fprintf function`

`7.19.6.1.9`

`If a conversion speciﬁcation is invalid, the behavior is **undeﬁned**. If any argument is
not  the  correct  type  for  the  corresponding  conversion  speciﬁcation,  the  behavior  is **undeﬁned**.`

So your code invokes **Undefined Behavior** [`(ISO C99 3.4.3)
behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
for which this International Standard imposes **no requirements**`]

> This should always segfault right!?

Not necessarily, Undefined Behavior means *anything* can happen.

Comment: Nicely researched, Prasoon, `+1` from me!

Comment: One day, I'm going to make a compiler that starts playing *Flight of the Valkyrie* every time undefined behavior is invoked.

Answer (score 10):

> This should always segfault right!?

No. This invokes *undefined behavior*. A segmentation fault is but one of many possible results of invoking UB.

Comment: +1: But this raises the following question: is there a way to ensure that something will cause a `SEGFAULT` ? (`kill my_program SEGFAULT` is not an answer)

Comment: `raise(SIGSEGV);` Or, while there's no standard that says this must work, *(char *)0=0; is also pretty reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Because printing a null reference as a string is (as far as I know, haven't verified with standards) undefined. Many systems will just output `(null)` in the result.

It's the same with the other printf functions:

```
printf ("%s", NULL); // Outputs (null) to the console on some systems but can crash others
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from that, a segfault is never guaranteed. If it occurs, there is an error somewhere; but having an error somewhere doesn't imply a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

> This should always segfault right!?

No. It depends on the implementation of the `sprintf` function that came with the standard library of the compiler.

As far as I know `sprintf` specification doesn't say you should provide a non-null address.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what bla is pointing to at the time.
What sprintf() will do is copy all of the characters pointed to by bla until it encounters a zero (0x00) character.

If it encounters a zero character before it reaches the limit of buf[100], then, there's no segfault because we are not writing beyond the buf limit.

Also, in some systems, if bla points to a read-access protected memory region, it may also cause a segfault as soon as the data is read.